# Macro for excel using recordset - optimization

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I’ve been trying to optimize following code:

```
Public cn As New ADODB.Connection
Public rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Public rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Public strsQL$
```

…

```
For c = 9 To 50

strsQL = "some SQL query"
rs.Open strsQL, cn
For r = 2 To 1000
        t = 0
        If c <> 9 Then
            For f = 9 To c - 1
                t = t + Sheet9.Cells(8 + (r - 2) * 6, f)
            Next f
        End If

        Set rs2 = rs.Clone
        rs2.Find ("x='" & Sheet9.Cells(r, 2) & "'")
        If rs2.EOF Then
            Sheet9.Cells(r, c) = ""
        Else
            If rs2.Fields("Total").Value - t <> 0 Then
                Sheet9.Cells(r, c) = rs2.Fields(1).Value - t
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    rs.Close
    rs2.Close
Next c
cn.Close
Close Connection
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
```

And here is my idea (or actually was because it is slower):

…

```
For c = 9 To 50        
strsQL = "some SQL query "
rs.Open strsQL, cn

Do While rs.EOF = False
t = 0
If Not ThisWorkbook.Sheet9.Range("B:B").Find(what:=rs.Fields(0).Value, 
LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

P_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheet9.Range("B:B").Find(what:=rs.Fields(0).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
adr_1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheet9.Cells(P_row + 4, 9).Address
adr_2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheet9.Cells(P_row + 4, c - 1).Address
t = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheet9.Range(adr_1 & ":" & adr_2))

If rs.Fields(1).Value - t > 0 Then
Sheet9.Cells(P_row, c) = rs.Fields(1).Value - t
End If
End If
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Next c

cn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

I do not understand why the runtime of second code is worse. First code goes through each column and for each column opens recordset and go through each row of column B from the worksheet in order to find if the row value is included in the recordset. So even if the searched row is not included in the recordset, the recordset is whole searched by command rs.find.
As each recordset has much less records than 1000 I was quite sure that it will be better for each column go through recordset and put the values only for found records as the rest can be left empty anyway . But it seems that it is not true.

And I have also used application.worksheetfunction.sum instead of summing in the loop but I don't expect it to be relevant as much.

Maybe anyone can help me to find what is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Consider posting the full working code (the version you're actually using) on [codereview.se], where you would be getting feedback on any/all aspects of the code - including and not limited to performance tuning. Make sure the title describes the purpose of the code, as opposed to what you're hoping to get for answers (CR has different posting rules than SO)

Comment: Have you checked to see if the indentation is making it faster?

Comment: Start by adding some timing, so you know *where* it's slow - for example if your database is slow your VBA is not going to make much difference.  In your second example you duplicate the Find() - there's no need for that.  It's not really that clear what you're doing, so it's difficult to make real suggestions.  Maybe try Match() instead of Find() - should be a little quicker.  Or create a row lookup using a Dictionary.  A single large DB query should (overall) be faster than multiple smaller ones.

Comment: Calling `rs.Clone` 998 times certainly can't be helping the performance.

Comment: For myself I get a little tired of fixing the same old basic mistakes and like to see some variety in the types of questions posted - I would not consider this question off-topic if we define "working code" as "functions to meet my requirements", since requirements can also include performance.  A "totally new approach" is pretty regularly suggested in answers here, so that shouldn't be off topic.

Comment: @Comintern I know that and I am not cloning, my current code is the second one. The issue here is that it seems that cloning is better, that is why I am confused and asked this question. But for now I suspect it is indeed because of Find() as Tim Williams suggested.